# Is Possible to read data/data folder files in Android?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

In Adobe Reader app(in lollipop version) using Share option to open Pdf file in My project cannot viewed but open with option is worked. I dont know what issue is. I checked the Path, but the Path is in Private data folder.

```
uri = content://com.adobe.reader.fileprovider/root_external/data/data/com.adobe.reader/files/Downloads/pdf-sample.pdf
```

Its possible to access this Path files. Unable to read this path. Can any one tell me how to do this

Answer (score 2):

> I checked the Path, but the Path is in Private data folder.

No, it is not. That is a `Uri`, not a path. Specifically, it is a `Uri` pointing to a `ContentProvider`, as you can tell from the `content://` scheme.

> Unable to read this path. Can any one tell me how to do this

Use `ContentResolver` to work with `content://` `Uri` values. In particular, you can use `openInputStream()` on `ContentResolver` to get an `InputStream` where you can read in the content associated with this `Uri`.

Comment: I get path from Uri. Path look like /root_external/data/data/com.adobe.reader/files/Downloads/pdf-sample.pdf

Comment: @Manoj: That is not a filesystem path. For all you know, that is a random series of characters.

Comment: Hello @Manoj can you please add answer which resolved your issue? Other users get help  from it.